# Proposal: Make "Featured on meta" a link to meta

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, navigation, community-bulletin

As the title says. The bit of text "Featured on Meta" makes for a reasonable and unobtrusive place to have a link to meta on the main page.

And on that note, it would be reasonable to make "Hot Meta Posts" a link to the corresponding tab.

Comment: Proposal makes perfect sense, but it would get more attention as an answer to [Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234453/259867) dedicated to collecting feedback on the redesign.

Comment: Anyway, I [posted there myself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234628/259867), though with a different proposal.